# Regex to strip tag only

Tags: php, regex

```
$re = '/(<(span|br)\b[^>]*>).*?(<\/\2>)/';
$str = '<p><span>Discover a new tough case for your iPhone 5 with Active Urban</span><span>™</span><span>&nbsp;Case from Cat phones.<br/>Made to survive the challenges of everyday life, this protective case will shield your device whether you\'ve chucked it in your bag, dropped it on the floor or left it in clumsy hands.<br>No matter the situation, the Active Urban</span><span>™</span><span>&nbsp;Case will live up to the challenge.</span></p>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

The issue with my regex is that it doesn't match self closing tags like `br` and also it selects the entire `span`, I just need to strip the tags, not its contents.

Comment: [`strip_tags`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: [Remove all html tags from php string](//stackoverflow.com/q/14684077)

Comment: @Tushar No, don't want to strip all tags, specific tags only.

Comment: regular expressions are shit at processing html

Comment: @Dagon True, but parsers aren't great either. I'm using HTMLPurifier and it strips a lot of important stuff. I guess you just have to use whatever works when working with crappy malformed HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<\/?\s*span\s*>|<\s*br\s*\/?\s*>
```

and replace by empty

```
$re = '/<\/?\s*span\s*>|<\s*br\s*\/?\s*>/m';
$str = '<p><span>Discover a new tough case for your iPhone 5 with Active Urban</span><span>™</span><span>&nbsp;Case from Cat phones.<br/>Made to survive the challenges of everyday life, this protective case will shield your device whether you\\\'ve chucked it in your bag, dropped it on the floor or left it in clumsy hands.<br>No matter the situation, the Active Urban</span><span>™</span><span>&nbsp;Case will live up to the challenge.</span></p>';
$subst = '';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DOre86/6)

Comment: `<\/?\s*(span|br)\/?\s*>` can be more shorter form. https://regex101.com/r/miu4kz/1

Comment: @Manwal true that , but it will match this : </span/> as well and </br /> as well. Although both are incorrect syntax

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt .. except that its highly unlike a `</span/>` or `</br />` would appear in HTML. ;)

Comment: @3zzy I already agreed that both are incorrect syntax. I just try to follow best practice. Which is, it should only match what it is supposed to match :)